# Copying greyed out files between drives

Tags: finder, hard-drive, external-disk, ntfs, exfat

I am trying to copy data from an external NTFS drive to an exFAT drive.

However, some files are greyed out and give me this error when I try to copy them:

> One or more items in “IMGP0029.AVI” can’t be changed because they are in use.

Even after clicking Continue and typing my password, it doesn't copy.

Following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136157/mov-file-in-external-hd-greyed-out-and-wont-open-this-item-is-used-by-mac-o) I tried to run `SetFile -c "" -t "" path/to/file.mov` but I get:

> ERROR: Write Permissions Error. (-61)  on file: /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/IMGP0029.AVI

Running `sudo chmod 777` gives me:

> chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/IMGP0029.AVI: Read-only file system

Where do I go from here?

Comment: MacOS can only read to NTFS file systems. That shouldn't stop you reading from them, but you can't modify them without third-party NTFS drivers.

Comment: Have you tried sudo?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround (which might not be suitable for everyone) was to copy the data onto a Windows PC, and then onto the destination drive.